# Resetting path for Truffle module

Tags: npm, terminal, solidity, truffle

I'm trying to follow along with this token tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ikc4Ct7wvk

When trying to use the **truffle** module, I cannot use any truffle command "command not found" unless I type in this path:

> ./node_modules/.bin/truffle"

How can I set this so that I don't need to specify this path to run the commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's globally installed you can execute `truffle` command. If it's locally installed you can `yarn run truffle` if you use Yarn package manager. Another way would be adding a shortcut to bashrc file.

I would recommend using Yarn package manager if you ask my recommendation.